# "Брачующиеся" и"брачащиеся"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Согласно новым правилам русского языка, теперь вместо "брачующиеся" надо говорить "брачащиеся". Но, по-моему, что первое, что второе - какие-то слова-уроды. Есть ли они вообще в русском языке или это, так сказать, профессиональный жаргон? И, кстати, как в последнем варианте ставится ударение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну в отношении "брачующихся" словарная фиксация давнишняя и повсеместная. А Лопатин даёт и "брАчащиеся". 
Выяснять, какая форма "правильнее", бессмысленно,  оба варианта окказиональны, поскольку порождающих глаголов ("брачевать(ся)" и "брачить(ся)" соответвенно) в русском языке нет и никогда не было. 
Появление, видимо, связано с тем, что "правильная" форма "бракующиеся" (от брак, браковать), давно "занята" другим значением.

Answer (score 0):

Мне не нравятся оба слова. Действительно, вряд ли кто-нибудь ,кроме работников ЗАГСа, употребляет "брачующиеся", "брачащиеся", и поэтому  их можно считать профессионализмами. Я бы сказала - "заключающие брак", "вступающие в брак"

Answer (score 0):

скорее соглашусь с тем, что "брачующиеся", "брачащиеся" - это слишком искусственно.
Ну нет например будущей формы в первом лице глагола "победить". 
Поэтому, "заключающие брак", "вступающие в брак" - это лучшее решение.